# Running a simple javafx application with gradle project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx

I am new to Eclipse java, Gradle and Javafx. Recently I am trying to write a javafx application with gradle project. The following are all sorts of details that I would like to provide.

[Javafx SDK version and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qauDF.png)

[Scene Builder version and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2DI8.jpg)

My question also arouses here, how does the filling actually work in Eclipse? Where should I place the driver class? Under src/main/java?

[My Eclipse directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUVj3.jpg)

This is how I format my user interface.

ui.fxml:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button1" layoutX="-317.0" layoutY="-145.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" text="Hit me" />
      <Label fx:id="label1" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="-98.0" text="hi" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = "11.0.2"
}

mainClassName = 'Library'
```

I doubt there are some issues here because when I run the gradle project, I can't run it. I could only build it.

[Gradle error: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'modules' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npm55.jpg)

Library.java: (the driver class)

```
public class Library {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ex2.UIApplication.run(arg);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I got quite a lot of errors.

[VM argument: --module-path "C:\Users\andes\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSD5S.jpg)

[Error: Could not find or load main class Lab_3_1.Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCpin.jpg)

Lab3Controller.java:

```
package ex2;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Lab3Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button button1;

    @FXML
    private Label label1;

    @FXML
    void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

UIApplication.java:

```
package ex2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UIApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ui.fxml"));
        VBox root = (VBox) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Lab 3");;
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void run (String arg[]) {
        Application.launch(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, your Mainclass exttends directly from Application.

You need to start it via a Class that does not extend from Application.

And start it from here.

```java
public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(UIApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also another tipp. 
If you want to run your application without "vm Arguments", you should consider a module-info.java to tell your application wich modules to use.

Or you can update you gradle configuration since you alreay use the Java fx plugin:

```
javafx {

    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml','javafx.graphics']
}

dependencies {

    // your other dependecies



    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx:11'
    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx', version: '11.0.2'



}


compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics'
        ]
        println options.compilerArgs
    }

}
```